# Op-Amp Based Multiplier LTSpice Simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, ltspice, multiplier, log-amplifier

I'm supposed to make a multiplier with log amplifier configuration using LM741 op-amps and 1N4001 diodes. I found this circuit configuration in [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anK6gqZAmgg). However, the output voltages I get are much different than what I am supposed to get, as seen at the figure. What am I doing wrong?

[image: LTSpice Circuit]

[image: Scope Output]

[image]
EDIT: Pink and cyan signals are the voltages on R3 and R4 resistors.

Comment: What do the voltage signals look like on the left nodes of R3 and R4. Please show a nice picture.

Comment: @Andyaka I've just updated with the new figure you asked for. Thanks.

Comment: Can you have those on a graph on their own at a bigger scale near full scale in y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a very practical implementation of a multiplier. It's single quadrant, also the theoretical output voltage has a multiplier factor of 1/(Is*R), which is a large and poorly controlled number.

The below shows you what the circuit is doing- the output voltage is only affected by the diodes and the resistor value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHqiKf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Theoretical output voltage for 2mV and 2mV is

Vo = -\$\frac{0.002 \cdot 0.002}{I_S\cdot R} = -1.558V\$ for Is = 7.7E-11A (the CircuitLab model for 1N4001). Shows good agreement.

If either of the input voltages are negative, the op-amps will rail, and for a 741 operating from +/-15V supplies (**and** the Is used in the Circuitlab model) the maximum input voltages are only a few mV before the output saturates. If you try to deal with this by reducing the output feedback resistor, the op-amp will run out of current drive quickly.

Since Is is not well controlled and is temperature-sensitive, the results will not be very good, especially outside of simulation land.

Suggest you look a little more deeply into practical log/antilog circuits. Also note that theoretical circuits showing a transistor will tend to oscillate under some conditions without added capacitors.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

That's a single quadrant multiplier, due to the two input opamps and the diodes in the feedback, so don't expect to see a sin()^2 at the output. And the output, even in the video it's clearly shown what you should expect:

$$\dfrac{V_1V_2}{I_SR}$$

If your two inputs are 2 mV and 3 mV, with a diode with a 1 nA saturation current you'll get 0.6 V at the output (with 10 kΩ resistor). Sure enough, LTspice (closely) agrees:

[image: test]

I don't have the model for the 741, but I used `[Opamps]/UniversalOpamp` with `Aol=100k GBW=1Meg Slew=1Meg`. The `.model` for the diode can be seen below.